# SQL - Split values from one column into two separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to take the value of column Quantity and split the values where Quantity is less than 500 and put those records into the LessThan500 column, for the records that are greater than 500 into the GreaterThan500 column.
I have a select statement that does this, but the table does not get updated properly

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Quantity < 500 THEN CAST(( Quantity*10 ) AS INT)
                 ELSE ''
            END) as Quantityx10
, SUM(CASE WHEN Quantity < 500 THEN CAST(( Quantity*10 ) AS INT)
                 ELSE ''
            END) AS '<500'
  , '' AS '>=500'


USE FET

-- Create a new template table
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.FuelSales', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.FuelSales; 

CREATE TABLE FuelSales
(
    TransactionType varchar(1) null,
    TransactionID int,
    CustomerID int null,
    TransactionDate date null,
    EntryTimeofDay datetime null,
    UserTranNumber varchar(15) null,
    AircraftNumber varchar(10) null,
    CompanyName varchar(40) null,
    NumNameCode varchar(30) null,
    Description varchar(40) null,
    Quantity decimal(18,6) null,
    LessThan500 decimal(18, 6) null,
    GreaterThan500 decimal(18,6) null,
);

INSERT INTO FuelSales(TransactionType, TransactionID, CustomerID, TransactionDate, EntryTimeofDay,UserTranNumber,AircraftNumber,CompanyName,NumNameCode,Description,Quantity,LessThan500,GreaterThan500)
SELECT ci.TransactionType
    , ci.TransactionID
    , ci.CustomerID
    , ci.TransactionDate
    , ci.EntryTimeofDay
    , ci.UserTranNumber
    , d.AircraftNumber
    , c.CompanyName
    , d.NumNameCode
    , d.Description
    , Quantity

  FROM [TFBO7].[dbo].[CustInv] ci
  INNER JOIN [TFBO7].[dbo].[Cust] c
  ON c.CustomerID=ci.CustomerID
  INNER JOIN [TFBO7].[dbo].[CustIDet] d
  ON ci.TransactionID=d.TransactionID      
  WHERE ci.TransactionDate between '20180701' and '20180731' and d.TransactionTypeID='1'
```

Comment: First for all, is this on MySQL or SQL Server? Can't be both.

Comment: SQL server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why would you do this permanently on the table and not just do the separation as an ad hoc query when needed but assuming it's SQL Server it would go something like this (in the `INSERT` statement you're already doing):

```
...
  , Quantity
    -- 500 has to go somewhere so I put it in the first category
  , LessThan500 = CASE WHEN Quantity <= 500 THEN Quantity ELSE NULL END
  , GreaterThan500 = CASE WHEN Quantity > 500 THEN Quantity ELSE NULL END
FROM [TFBO7].[dbo].[CustInv] ci
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a computed column to the table.  Just do:

```
alter table fuelsales add lessthan500 as (case when quantity <= 500 then quantity end);
alter table fuelsales add greaterthan500 as (case when quantity > 500 then quantity end);
```

This column will appear in the table when you query the table.  However, it is not stored and it is "updated" automatically when `quantity` changes.